# App to Manage Email Incoming Settings

Tags: java, android

I need to develop an android application that can allow users to easily change the password on the corporate account on their androids like in the screen below. The main goal is to avoid the long list of menus that they have to click through (and IT has to talk them through). NOTE: This only needs to change the locally saved password.

My first idea was to use the AccountManager setPassword function, but I received an error saying that the uid was different. From the looks of it, I would have to create and manage the account (including email, sync, and all that junk) within my app if I were to follow this method since AccountManager does not allow apps to mess with the data of other apps (Duh). I don't think this is really feasible.

My second idea was to simply launch the settings screen below from within my application. I'm relatively new to Android development, but have seen a lot of different intents used to launch specific settings. Is launching the specific account settings possible?

[Incoming Corporate Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KRtm.png)

Comment: That would appear to be a screen from a specific email app. Contact the authors of that app and ask them if there is an `Intent` to drive straight to that screen. If it exists, that's not a great sign (those sorts of activities should not be exported), but it would allow you to accomplish your aim.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare . This is actually a picture from the stock Email application from Google. I take it that isn't likely exportable?

Comment: I doubt that Google has documented anything about it. Now, I'm not sure if that app is the AOSP Email app. If it is, the app is open source, and you are welcome to putter through its manifest (e.g., [4.4 MR2](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Email/+/kitkat-mr2.2-release/AndroidManifest.xml)). Curiously, an `AccountSettings` *is* exported, and so you're welcome to try crafting an `com.android.email.activity.setup.ACCOUNT_MANAGER_ENTRY` `Intent` for it. Just bear in mind that undocumented stuff like this can break with any update to the app you're linking to.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks again for your help. That got me a lot closer. That intent took me to the account's general settings, but I still need to drill down 2 more levels for it to be worth it. If I were to return to the account manager method, would there be a way to edit the data (i.e. password) from the other app?

Comment: "If I were to return to the account manager method, would there be a way to edit the data (i.e. password) from the other app?" -- I sure hope not, for obvious security reasons.

Comment: @CommonsWare I figured as much, but with limited experience on Android, thought it was worth an ask. Appreciate the help.